# SQL query for multiple row values stored a CLOB

Tags: sql

I have 2 unique ids 123 and 234 stored as 2 xml in a db table in a CLOB field . How can i query for these 2 ids at the same time in the xml.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name  Oracle